# Match string between curly brackets, if including pattern

Tags: json, regex, awk, grep

In a log I’d like to match all json objects which type is "sync.out.notify.job.status" and print them. I’m on a Mac (zsh).

I tried: `grep -Eo \{.+"sync\.out\.notify\.job\.status".+\}`

```
Mon Jan 11 2021 13:08:46 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) CoreSyncNotifications: sync.out.notify.job.status:
{
  "cloudid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "job": "files",
  "majorstate": "syncing",
  "minorstate": "transferring",
  "requestid": "45768456-bd58-4cb5-9dff-dfgjfgdj456",
  "type": "sync.out.notify.job.status",
  "userid": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@AdobeID",
  "version": "1.1.43711"
}
Mon Jan 11 2021 13:08:46 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) Vulcan: <- COSY 4.3: sync.out.notify.job.status
Mon Jan 11 2021 13:08:46 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) CoreSyncNotifications: sync.out.notify.job.status:
{
  "errors": "",
  "cloudid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "job": "files",
  "majorstate": "idle",
  "minorstate": "complete",
  "requestid": "4856658fdgh-efb3-4da9-b5f5-4856658fgj",
  "type": "sync.out.notify.job.status",
  "userid": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@AdobeID",
  "version": "1.1.43711"
}
Mon Jan 11 2021 13:08:46 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) WebSocketServer: client_7: SEND syncstate creative_cloud: ok
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the blocks that match? Print them? Delete them? Modify them? Please [edit] your question to provide the expected output given your posted sample input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` usually searches pattern in single line only unless you use `-z` option in `gnu grep`.

You may try this `gnu awk` command:

```sh
awk -v RS='(^|\n){[^}]+?sync.out.notify.job.status[^}]+}(\n|$)' 'RT {printf "%s", RT}' file

{
  "cloudid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "job": "files",
  "majorstate": "syncing",
  "minorstate": "transferring",
  "requestid": "45768456-bd58-4cb5-9dff-dfgjfgdj456",
  "type": "sync.out.notify.job.status",
  "userid": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@AdobeID",
  "version": "1.1.43711"
}

{
  "errors": "",
  "cloudid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "job": "files",
  "majorstate": "idle",
  "minorstate": "complete",
  "requestid": "4856658fdgh-efb3-4da9-b5f5-4856658fgj",
  "type": "sync.out.notify.job.status",
  "userid": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@AdobeID",
  "version": "1.1.43711"
}
```

Comment: This works for my example but the log is a little more complex than that. I updated the example.

Comment: nit: isn't `[^}]+?` just `[^}]*`?

Comment: @jthill: No `[^}]+?` is different from `[^}]*`. Different is greediness

Comment: I don't see any exception in the docs for it, `+` is differentiated only in requiring at least one match, where are you getting this from?

Comment: `[^}]+?` is a repetition metachar `+` followed by a 2nd repetition metachar `?` which is undefined behavior in an ERE so what any awk variant does with it is up to whoever provided that awk but the `?` is probably ignored. `{[^}]` **may** also be undefined behavior too since `{` is the start of an RE interval definition but here it's not followed by an RE interval (e.g. `{3,7}`), I'd always escape the `{` or enclose it in a bracket expression even if just for clarity to the reader so I'm not sure if it's defined as-is or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily and robustly use a JSON-aware tool like `jq` for this, assuming you want to print the matching blocks:

```
$ grep -v '^[[:alpha:]]' file | jq 'select(.type=="sync.out.notify.job.status")'
{
  "cloudid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "job": "files",
  "majorstate": "syncing",
  "minorstate": "transferring",
  "requestid": "45768456-bd58-4cb5-9dff-dfgjfgdj456",
  "type": "sync.out.notify.job.status",
  "userid": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@AdobeID",
  "version": "1.1.43711"
}
{
  "errors": "",
  "cloudid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "job": "files",
  "majorstate": "idle",
  "minorstate": "complete",
  "requestid": "4856658fdgh-efb3-4da9-b5f5-4856658fgj",
  "type": "sync.out.notify.job.status",
  "userid": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@AdobeID",
  "version": "1.1.43711"
}
```

Here's another way to get from { to } to pipe to jq:

```
$ sed -n '/^{/,/^}/p' file
{
  "cloudid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "job": "files",
  "majorstate": "syncing",
  "minorstate": "transferring",
  "requestid": "45768456-bd58-4cb5-9dff-dfgjfgdj456",
  "type": "sync.out.notify.job.status",
  "userid": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@AdobeID",
  "version": "1.1.43711"
}
{
  "errors": "",
  "cloudid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "job": "files",
  "majorstate": "idle",
  "minorstate": "complete",
  "requestid": "4856658fdgh-efb3-4da9-b5f5-4856658fgj",
  "type": "sync.out.notify.job.status",
  "userid": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@AdobeID",
  "version": "1.1.43711"
}
```

I normally wouldn't suggest using a range expression over using a flag but in this case since it's ALL you're going to do with it, it's probably fine.

Comment: Wow thats great. Still I get an parse error. I think it is because `grep -v '^[[:alpha:]]' file` 
 outputs lines like: `<- [SERVICE_IS_INACTIVE] Network request in inactive state`

Comment: Then change the regexp I used in the grep to suit your real input. All I had to go on when creating it was the sample input you provided. I added an alternative way to get the json parts too but again it's just based on the input youve shown so far,